# How to add 'refresh wifi networks' to my connections menu

Tags: wireless, taskbar, editing

My laptop is slow on refreshing the wifi networks on the list of available networks and I would like to edit in a button to refresh the list. Currently I know I can do this in the command line using this `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`,

Currently it looks like this.:

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi5f2.png)

Answer (score 2):

You asked `How to add 'refresh wifi networks' to my connections menu`. The simple answer is "You can't". NetworkManager is a system indicator, which means it's written in C, and you have to get source code of this applet, edit it to suit your needs, and recompile.

By contrast, far simpler approach is to take `iwlist wlan0 scan` command, and bind it to a keyboard shortcut via `System Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Custom`  menu. Note also that you don't need `sudo` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a point and click solution, you could install [indicator-script-runner](https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335) and create a "script" which uses the command `iwlist wlan0 scan` as given by @Serg or similar.